# Glossaries package: \glsresetall with exceptions

Tags: glossaries

At the start of each chapter I use \glsresetall. However, there are certain abbreviations so commonly known by the audience I am writing for that it seems unnecessary to refresh their memory in each chapter.

Is there a way to reset all glossary terms with exceptions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked into the documentation and found something interesting called `\glslocalunset`. If you want to use a list instead of multiple calls for every abbreviation, switch to the `glossaries-extra` package and its `\glslocalunseteach` command.

However for a next question, please take your time and provide at least a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\loadglsentries{example-glossaries-acronym}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
    
\chapter{First}
Use of \gls{upa}, \gls{ulc} and \gls{afm} 

\chapter{Second}
\glsresetall
\glslocalunset{upa}

Use of \gls{upa}, \gls{ulc} and \gls{afm} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works well.